# Etimología de "despistar". Relación entre "pistar" y "pista"

Tags: etimología, verbos, sustantivos

Hoy me ha dado por preguntarme la etimología del verbo *despistar*, dado que parece casi obvio que es una palabra formada por *des-* y un supuesto verbo *pistar*, que significaría lo opuesto de *despistar*. Sin embargo:

> **[despistar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DMlzkpQ)**
>
> 1. tr. Hacer perder la pista. U. t. c. intr.
> 2. tr. Distraer, desorientar o confundir. Perdí la cuenta porque un ruido me despistó. U. t. c. intr.
> 3. intr. Fingir, disimular.
> 4. prnl. Extraviarse, perder el rumbo.

Y:

> **[pistar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDTeva1)**
>
> Del it. dialect. *pistare*, y este del lat. tardío *pistāre*.
>
> 1. tr. Machacar, aprensar algo o sacarle el jugo.

Vale, de momento veo que, efectivamente, existe un verbo *pistar*. Pero no tiene precisamente el significado que yo esperaba. Y el DLE no indica etimología para *despistar*.

El verbo *pistar* se usaba en el siglo XVI (y en textos anteriores en latín tardío como *pistare*):

> *Madona, no; mas haré d'esta manera, que pistaré el almáciga y la grana y el alumbre, y se lo daré, y diré que sea esa misma, y haré un poco de olio de habas, y diré que se lo ponga con el colirio, que es apropiado para los ojos, y ansí no sabrá que vuestra señoría tiene lo más perfeto.*
>
> Francisco Delicado, "La Lozana Andaluza", 1528 (España).

Este verbo *pistar* se recoge en diccionarios desde 1617, y mi intuición es que de ahí surgió el sustantivo *[pista](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDQL0Vc)*, también del italiano dialectal *pista*, con el significado de *rastro*. La primera aparición de esta palabra es en el *Diccionario de autoridades*:

> PISTA. s. f. La huella que dexan los animales, por donde se les sigue. Lat. *Vestigium*.

También se usaba en el siglo XVI, aunque más tarde:

> *Aviendo de hazer emboscadas, o poner gente en celada, han de tener el mismo aviso de los ramos para borrar la pista y que no se vea que están en ella, advirtiendo, si es possible, no relinchar los cavallos [...].*
>
> Bernardino de Mendoza, "Teórica y práctica de guerra", 1598 (España).

Hasta entonces la palabra que se usaba (y sigue usando) con el mismo significado era *rastro*:

> RASTRO. s. m. La señál que dexa impressa en la tierra qualquier cosa que ha passado por ella. Lat. *Vestigium*.

Y ya de *pista* surgió *despistar*, que no aparece en el DLE hasta 1884, únicamente como "hacer perder la pista". Aunque se usaba desde el siglo XVII:

> *Que son de lince, señora,
>
>   los ojos de la sospecha;
>
>   que por más que los enredes
>
>   y quieras entretenellos,
>
>   despistando cuanto puedes,
>
>   pasa la agudeza dellos
>
>   diligencias y paredes.*
>
> Carlos Boil, "El marido asigurado", 1616 (España).

Todo esto suena muy bien y parece muy bonito, pero aun así hay algo que no me cuadra. ¿Cuál es exactamente la relación entre *pistar* como "machacar" y *pista* como "rastro"? Esa conexión es la que se me escapa un poco. ¿Es posible que el camino hacia la palabra *despistar* en realidad haya sido otro? ¿Me he equivocado en algún paso?

Nota: soy consciente de que el cambio de significado entre una y otra palabra pudo producirse en el italiano antes de llegar al español, en cuyo caso remitiré la pregunta al sitio de italiano.

Comment: En **pistar** dice *aprensar algo*, para dejar una huella se hace presión contra algo (el suelo normalmente), y una huella es una pista también como comentas. No sé si es muy rebuscado. Por otra parte, ¿por qué el DLE usa *aprensar* en lugar de *prensar* en la definición siendo esta una palabra en desuso
?

Comment: I had always assumed it was like the English phrase 'going off piste'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En latín clásico, [*pista*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pista#Latin) era la forma femenina o neutra (según el caso) de [*pistus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pistus#Latin), que a su vez es el participio del verbo [*pīnsō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinso#Latin), verbo que significa: **golpear, moler, machacar**.
Una de las formas de [supino](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supino) de *pīnsō* es *pistum*, la cual por su parte tiene una forma [frecuentativa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IQxDYbC) que es [*pistō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pisto#Latin), cuyo verbo es... [***pistāre***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pistare#Latin).

Dicho de otra manera: "*pista, pīnsō, pistō, pistāre*" es en latín lo que "pisada, pisar, pisoteo, pisotear" en español, solo que significando "golpear, machacar, moler" en vez de "pisar".

Por otra parte, pensemos en el concepto de rastro: no es más que la sucesión de sitios en los que encontramos señales del paso del animal o enemigo al que estamos siguiendo. Señales como una planta machacada, una rama golpeada, la tierra removida y pulverizada...
El mismo concepto de pista, como camino, no es más que un sendero hecho por animales y personas (y, hoy día, todoterrenos) a base de machacar y pisotear repetidamente la vegetación y los accidentes del terreno para ir de un sitio a otro.

Así, es fácil usar pista en sentido figurado para hablar de algo que te lleva a tu objetivo (como el rastro que han dejado los animales a los que persigues). En sentido no tan figurado también puede ser directamente un rastro, aunque no haya un camino propiamente dicho visible sobre el terreno.

Y como ya has visto en la etimología indicada por el DLE, el verbo latino *pistāre* en italiano quedó sustantivado y reducido a, de nuevo, [**pista**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pista#Italian), con los significados ya establecidos, y de ahí pasó al español.

Otros vocablos en español con etimología a partir de *pistāre* serían [pisto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDdbwD7) y [pistón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDwyqlf).